# cannot load data for ECG example from MATLAB

Tags: database, matlab, signal-processing

I am working on ECG signal processing using MATLAB and an example is [provided by The MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/wavelet/mw/wavelet-ex77408607-r-wave-detection-in-the-ecg).

In this example, an ECG waveform called "mit200" is loaded, and it is taken from the MIT-BIH Arrythmia Database. I want to test out this example, so I tried to get the data from the [MIT-BIH Arrythmia Database website](http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM), but when I run the code I get the following error:

> Undefined function or variable 'tm'

Can someone please guide me how to get the exact data as the example? I chose the following parameters on http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM:

```
Database: MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database (mitdb)
Record: 200
Signals: all
Length: 10 sec
Time format: time/date
Data format: standard
Toolbox: Export signals as .mat
```

NOT A DUPLICATE:
I have already looked into another post that explains how to get .mat file, but the .mat file does not match the one from the example

Comment: Not a duplicate. I looked into it, and it only explains how to get the .mat file, but this .mat file does not match the example

Comment: If you look at the `.mat` file you have downloaded, you'll notice that it only has a `val` variable inside (the reason for your issue). The accepted answer in the linked question shows how to construct the time vector (`tm` in the example).